# Can I pass a vector as an argument to datomic query?

Tags: datomic

if i had a schema (in pseudocode)

```
{:collection/name 
 :type "string"}, 
{:photo/collection
 :type ref}
```

And I had a vector of 3 collections from which I wanted to see all photos.

Can I do something like below? (show me all photos that are in collection A, B, or C

```
:find [?p]
:where [?p :photo/collection [17592186045568 17592186045597 17592186045654]]
```

I get the following error when I try something like this..

```
IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo :db.error/invalid-lookup-ref Invalid list form: [[17592186045568 17592186045597 17592186045654]]  datomic.error/arg (error.clj:55)
```

If I can't do this like this, is there some other way I can go about this?

Update:

I see in the tutorial there is a way to pass a vector using ... (btw is there a name for this kind of query?) and I tried

```
{:query {:find [?p ?coll], :where [[?p :photo/collection ?coll]], :in [$ [?coll ...]]}
```

With [17592186045568 17592186045597 17592186045654] as an input, but I still get the same error. It seems my syntax is correct because I did try this with another attribute (not a ref) and it worked ok. I'm just stuck on refs. There has to be a best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this using a collection [binding](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#bindings). There are some simple illustrations of this [here](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/tutorial/binding.clj#L16-L30).

There's a collection restructuring section in [Learn Datalog Today!](http://www.learndatalogtoday.org/chapter/3#collections) (and problem 1 uses this, if you want to try to verify that the syntax of your solution is correct).

A similar approach to your problem might read:

```
(d/q '[:find ?pid ?collection
       :in $ [?collection ...]
       :where [?p :photo/collections ?collection]
              [?p :photo/id ?pid]]
    (d/db conn)
    ["A" "B" "C"])
```

The results would be something like this (assuming simple integer photo ids - I'm not sure how you're actually identifying photos):

```
[1 "A"]
[2 "A"]
[3 "B"]
```

If you just want entity id's, you should be able to use the simpler query:

```
[:find ?p
 :in $ [?collection ...]
 :where
 [?p :photo/collection ?collection]]
```